# Conics Question - Areas

Tags: conic-sections

Problem Statement:

> Square $ABCD$ has side length $60$. An ellipse $E$ is circumscribed about the square and there is a point $P$ on the ellipse such that $PC = PD =50$. What is  the area of $E$?

I have absolutely no idea nor any thoughts I can write down here. How would I approach this problem? How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Let's write the ellipse like:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

And the vertex: $A(-30,30),B(30,30),C(30,-30),D(-30,-30),$ so once those belong to the ellipse then

$$\frac{900}{a^2}+\frac{900}{b^2}=1$$

We also have, $PC=50=PD$, $P(x_0,y_0)$:

$$(x_0-30)^2+(y_0+30)^2=50^2\\
(x_0+30)^2+(y_0+30)^2=50^2$$

After find $P(x_0,y_0)$ and remembering that it belongs to the elipse you can find $a$ and $b$.

And the area will be given by $\pi \cdot a\cdot b$.

Can you finish?